# How to tunnel through a SINGLE PORT using sshuttle?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I can tunnel my whole network traffic using `sshuttle` by this simple following command (which `digitalocean` is my IP address and I have a public key, saved there):

```sh
sudo sshuttle --dns -r root@digitalocean -x digitalocean  0/0
```

I don't know how to make the `sshuttle` tunnel through one specific port (like 8800) so that I can access my local nearby server and use a browser (e.g. Firefox) tunnelled through that port: using a Manual proxy with `localhost:8800` address.

I know that I can use the following command to tunnel my traffic through a specific port (like 8800), but as I don't have the password of this digitalocean server, I'm not able to use `ssh` to access it.

```sh
sudo ssh -N -D 8800 root@digitalocean
```

Comment: No it's no possible with sshuttle, you could try proxychains

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for similar things this is in fact very straightforward:

```
sshuttle --dns -r user@host:8800 0/0 -x host
```